# How to save result in separate column in excel from shell script?

Tags: shell, testing, automation, behat

I am saving the executed result in one of the excel sheet. The result will show in new rows like below:

[image]

I have used the below command :

```
$ bash eg.sh Behatscripts.txt | egrep -w 'Executing the|scenario' >> output.xls
```

I want to display result like below:

```
|                  A                   |          B           |       c     |
1 Executing the script:cap_dutch_home    1 scenario(1passed)
2 Executing the script:cap_english_home  1 scenario(1passed)
```

One more thing is while executing it will create output.xls separate file, instead of using already existed.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this;

with awk;

```
bash eg.sh Behatscripts.txt | egrep -w 'Executing the|scenario' | awk 'BEGIN {print "Column_A\tColumn_B"}NR%2{printf "%s \t",$0;next;}1' output.xls
```

without egrep

```
bash eg.sh Behatscripts.txt | awk '/Executing the|scenario/' | awk 'BEGIN {print "Column_A\tColumn_B"}NR%2{printf "%s \t",$0;next;}1' >> output.xls
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but its displaying in a same column 'A', not in the next column 'B'.

Comment: Your solution works great.. One more help is required,Please let me know if u know the solution. I want to put titles(headings) for the columns,is it possible to do?

Comment: I tried this but not worked. $ bash eg.sh Behatscripts.txt | awk '/Executing the|scenario/' | awk 'BEGIN{Print "Title\tResult"}1' | awk 'NR%2{printf "%s \t",$0;next;}1' >> output.xls. Please suggest some modification.

Comment: I updated ans. Could you try this? ' P should be lowercase in BEGIN{Print "Title\tResult"..., use BEGIN{print ...}

Comment: Thanks for the changes. One more help is required bro. How can i print all results after 3rd line of excel sheet into second column not in first column. I tried this.  bash eg.sh Behatscripts.txt | awk '/Executing the|scenario/' | awk NR>2{printf "%s \t",$0;next;}1' >> output.xls